# xml to json to jsonp converter

Tags: xml, json, rss, jsonp

Does such a converter exist?

For example, I want to convert the following:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/travelnews/tpeg/cy/regions/rtm/wales_rss.xml

to pure jsonp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this query](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20xml%20where%20url=%27http://www.bbc.co.uk/travelnews/tpeg/cy/regions/rtm/wales_rss.xml%27&format=json&callback=cbfunc) using YQL ?

```
select * from xml where url='http://www.bbc.co.uk/travelnews/tpeg/cy/regions/rtm/wales_rss.xml'
```

Comment: Is this real time?  For example, if the source is updated tomorrow, and I access that link after the update, will the jsonp get automatically updated based on the source update?

Answer (score 0):

[XSLT](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/) can be used to convert from XML to JSON. From there it's trivial to convert to JSONP.

Comment: How do I apply XSLT on an xml file on a remote host to which I have no control over?

Answer (score 0):

if it's just a one time conversion you could use:

http://jsoneditor.net/

To convert to JSON